# How can I use IBus as the default input method?

Tags: ibus, input

I have found IBus installed in my fresh elementary OS. But I cannot use it over default system layouts. I prefer IBus because, it supports the m17n engine which includes my preferred layout for writing Bengali. From system layouts which is not accessible.

How can I use IBus over the system layouts? If IBus is not usable, then why it is installed by default in elementary OS?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. 
First you setup your `ibus` by command `ibus-setup`
[image]

---

Chose the `Input Method` tab.

### [image]

--> `Select an input method` --> `Add` language what do you want.
My example is **Vietnamese - Unikey** as you see in the picutre.
**Vietnamese** is language
**Unikey** is type of input

---

After `Add` language you will go to `Application` --> `System Settings` --> `Keyboard` --> `Universal Access` 
You will see the `Next Keyboard Layout` is your shortcut to change your `ibus`.
[image]

---

Finally if you want to add your language in your `System Tray` .
Use this command `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'us'), ('ibus', '**YOUR TYPE**')]"​`

### Example `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'us'), ('ibus', 'Unikey')]"​`

Remember Unikey is my `input` from vietnamese . Just replace your type.

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: it works but not in libreoffice and other apps.  Some apps it works.  Something is missing.

Comment: I don't have the "Next Keyboard Layout" option..

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following to solve the problem-

1. Install your desired input method for **IBus**.
2. Run `ibus-setup` command from **terminal**.
3. Select 'Input method' tab and **Add** your desired input method.
4. Close 'IBus Setup' and run `ibus-daemon -drx` in **terminal**.

It starts IBus daemon but It doesn't show IBus on the panel, but it brings up the input method popup and let us choose our desired input method.

If you IBus to automatically start with the system, then go to **Settings** > **Applications** > **Startup** and add `ibus-daemon -drx` as a custom command.

If you want to use any QT/KDE applications, you have to install the package `ibus-qt4` as well:

```
sudo apt install ibus-qt4
```

Comment: I got the keyboard to be selected and I can select with alt space, but the keys do not work (they used to in gnome).  please help.  I suspect it is because I have synapse installed.  can you verify this synapse bug on your machine?