# How to use IPA Keyboard layouts in Freya

Tags: wingpanel, keyboard, input

I've been trying to install the [SIL IPA Unicode Keyboard](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=UniIPAKeyboard#dfc8e3bf) to no avail. Steps taken:

1. Added the packages.sil.org ubuntu trusty repo (they don't have one for elementary or freya)
2. `sudo apt-get install ibus-kmfl`
3. `sudo apt-get install kmfl-keyboard-ipa`
4. Configured everything via the instructions here: [How can I use IBus as the default input method?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2371/how-can-i-use-ibus-as-the-default-input-method). I was able to add the IPA keyboard to the list of active ibus input methods. Added the label to the system tray as per the instructions, but whenever I click on the label, it switches me back to the default (US) keyboard layout.

Additionally, the ibus panel icon does not display in the system tray, even though the option is checked in ibus-settings. So it seems as though Freya is still not recognizing ibus (or at least, my keyboard) as the input source for some reason.

Has anybody else managed to install the IPA keyboard? Or any other custom .kmn file?