# Elementary OS 5.0 Juno is not using ibus as input method

Tags: keyboard, release-juno, input, keyboard-layout, ibus

I'm not able to make Elementary OS use ibus as a default input method (IM). I have installed ibus but I'm not sure what I have to do further. Why I think it's not used as IM is because I've de-selected the "Share same input method among all applications" and still when I switch the language, it is still switched globally. The other reason why I made this assumption is that the OS doesn't take into account what languages I have added in the ibus-setup settings and still uses whatever is chosen in the default settings.

I know this question has been raised before, but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Have you tried any of the proposed solutions [in this question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2371/how-can-i-use-ibus-as-the-default-input-method)?

Comment: Yes but without success. I don't even have that option in the "Universal access" settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

1. Open im-config through terminal

   sudo im-config

   [image]

click OK button to go next

2. Click Yes to update system config.
   [image]
3. Select Ibus as input method for the system
   [image]
4. Click Ok and Ok for the next windows. Then restart your computer.

---

The `sudo` at step 1 is crucial. Without `sudo` the system just uses the default setting regardless of what you have chosen.

Also make `ibus-daemon` auto start with the system by:

`System Settings` > `Applications` > `Startup`

Then add a custom command:

```
ibus-daemon -drx
```

Answer (score 0):

I use 5.1.3 Hera which pre-installed IBus (IBus preference panel can be found in System Settings > Keyboard > Layout > Input Method Settings). 
dragon2fly's answer solves my problem.

Just select IBus in 'im-config', restart, and it works.