# How to install and use Avro keyboard in Elementary OS 5.0 Juno?

Tags: keyboard, language, ibus

I am new in elementary os. Previously I was using Windows 10. I am trying to be used to in elementary os. I have to write some of my documents in Bangla language. Is it possible to get avro or any other phonetic Bangla keyboard to write down Bangla more easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open terminal and type

   ```
   $ sudo apt install ibus-avro
   ```
2. Type in terminal `sudo im-config` and select **OK** then **Yes**
3. Select **Ibus** as input method for the system
4. Click **Ok** and **Ok** for the next windows. Then restart your computer.
5. Type in terminal `ibus-setup` and remember your keyboard shortcut to switch layout, in our case it's `Ctrl + Space`
6. Choose **Input Method** tab and Click **Add** button then "**:**" icon for more list
7. Choose **Bengali** and select **Avro Phonetic** which you need.
   [More in Details](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2371/how-can-i-use-ibus-as-the-default-input-method)
8. Done! Now you can switch layout using Shortcut mention above.

Comment: আলহামদুলিল্লাহ, জাজাকাল্লাহু খাইরান!
It works!
Now Bangla typing is at ease with Avro in Elementary.