# Japanese keyboard

Tags: keyboard, language

I want to type japanese characters but I can't setup japanese keyboard. I added new japanese language in settings but it seems that I only can type latin characters with it.

I tried to use IBus, but it sounds like IBus doesn't override system-specified keyboard and I can't find any setting to set IBus as system-default keyboard manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems solved with installation of `im-config` and setting `ibus` method. ありがとう！

Answer (score 1):

Go to system settings, then "language & region" and use the "plus symbol" in the lower left of the window to add Japanese as an language. Set region and format as you like. These steps might be optional, I didn't try.

Then click to keyboard settings (lower most left big button). Again click the "plus symbol" on the lower left and search for japanese. When you single click to it, choose a layout to your liking. You can inspect the layout with the small button on the lower left depicting a small latin "a". For some reason the Standard layout is not with any japanese symbols.

Also note that in the same main window you got additional "input method settings" as a button on the lower right.

Reboot or logout to make the new keyboard settings work. You should now have a symbol in the top menu bar where you can switch and inspect your configured keyboard languages & layouts.

**If you have issues with IBus** not being the "default input method" you can follow the instructions from here: [How can I use IBus as the default input method?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2371/how-can-i-use-ibus-as-the-default-input-method)

**If you need other layouts like Hiragana** you can check out the instructions here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/28669/how-do-i-get-keyboard-to-write-hiragana-instead-of-katakana

**If you like the terminal** you can always use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` for the same stuff.

As a sitenote: I just messed up my own keyboard settings with trying this and for some reason I always need two configured languages for the keyboard so it's working properly.

Comment: Well... yeah, that works for Katakana, but... how can I type Hiragana then? And, more importantly, how can I type hieroglyphs? I am not sure that standard keyboard suffices for that.

Comment: You are right. I checked every single option one by one and there is no Hiragana.

Comment: I updated my answer with some hints for IBus and Hiragana layout. I hope this makes it work.

Answer (score 1):

Please note *Keyobard layout* and *Input Method* are seperated. *Keyboard layout* should follow your physical keyboard. Then add the required *Input Method*.

Also, for the Japanese keyboard layout found in eOS. I found no way to do transform and only Katakana can be inputted.

---

For adding *Input Method*, please follow these steps.

- **System Settings > Keyboard**

[image: System Settings]

- **Keyboard > Input Method Settings...**
  [image: Keyboard]
- **IBus Preferences > Input Method > Add**
  [image: IBus Preferences]
- **Pick the required language**

[image: IBus Preferences]

- **Pick the input method.**

[image]

---

Under **General** tag, set the **Keyboard Shortcuts** for changing input method. Tweak other settings to fit your needs.

*Please note **Show icon on system tray** don't work by default as eOS removed support.
[image]

Here is the pop-up menu for changing input method.

[image: IBus input select]

Choosing character type by clcking that `A`.

[image]

Comment: The thing is, IBus doesn't work at all. It says to set IBus as default input method in settings, but I can't find any way how to do it.

Comment: What source are you refering? Can you describ your situation?

Comment: Well, I do everything right as you show. And IBus daemon is activated, but when I type something, plain english appears. I have even tried to type russian - still, default system keyboard layout is used.

Comment: Added the 'Chosing charaters type' at the end. Hope it help.

Comment: Nah, it doesn't. I don't have "A". Well, thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: It may be hidden. Goto 'IBus Preferences > General > Font and Style > Show preperty panel:' to set its behaviour.

Comment: Well, I see the panel, but system default keyboard is still in use.